# Getting timezone information on iPhone for coordinates

Tags: iphone, timezone, geolocation, location, nstimezone

For iPhone development:
How can I get the timezone and DST information for any place given that I only have geographic coordinates. (NSTimezone does not have any such method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a web service ([like so](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone)). I believe with this particular service you are limited to one request per second. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

[DRT Engine](http://drtengine.com/pages/geo_get_timezone) will return a timezone offset when passed geographic coordinates (latitude/longitude) and a datetime.